# How to start elasticsearch on a CentOS?

Tags: centos, elasticsearch

I have downloaded the latest elasticsearch version 5.5.1 on my Centos 7 server from https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch. I have unzipped the file and store it in elasticsearch directory.

I have tried to start the elasticsearch using the below commands (Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-targz.html):

```
1)./bin/elasticsearch
```

Error: Permission denied

```
2) sudo ./bin/elasticsearch
```

Error: sudo: ./bin/elasticsearch: command not found
**Although there is no administrator user on my server.**

```
3)cd bin
./elasticsearch
```

Error Permission denied

```
4) cd bin
sudo ./elasticsearch
```

Error: sudo: ./elasticsearch: command not found

```
5) cd bin
./elasticsearch.in.sh
```

This command doesn't give me output

When I do wget http://localhost:9200, I get:

```
--2017-08-01 14:01:25--  http://localhost:9200/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:9200... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:9200... failed: Connection refused.
```

May I know is this the right way to start the elasticsearch on a centos server. Do I have to change any setting in the configuration file before starting it.

Comment: please run `ls -al elasticsearch.in.sh` in the directory where it is and let me see the output

Comment: Is `Error: Permission denied` the full error message? If not, please include the full error output.  Elastic also provides RPMs that might be a bit easier to get started with https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rpm.html

Comment: @george The output is: -rw-rw-r--. 1 centos centos 8075 Jul 18 23:42 elasticsearch

Comment: @steeve Yes. It;s the only error. I can try to install using rpms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok please make it executable with:

```
sudo chmod +x elasticsearch.in.sh
```

Then run it `sudo ./elasticsearch.in.sh`

And we have the option to use an `rpm` package from [here](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch), Download the file `elasticsearch-5.5.1.rpm` and install with:

```
sudo rpm -ivh elasticsearch-5.5.1.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks. I made elasticsearch executed and ran ./elasticsearch from the bin folder. It worked